# IOS - Possible to receive notification when user receives a text?

Tags: ios, ios5

Is it possible to receive a notification when a user has received a text within the iOS SDK?
For example if your app is running, and you want to track the number of text messages received while the app is in the foreground.

I know it's not possible, I just wanted some additional confirmation for my higher-ups
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. Apple will never do this as it's a huge privacy violation.

You may be able to infer something happened by noticing your app resigned active, but that's a  very unreliable measure of anything interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the normal SDK. Probably for jailbroken phones.

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s not possible.

Also, you can’t detect if the user receives an iMessage.

And since you may resign active for any number of reasons (like getting a phone call), you can’t really infer anything.